# Magic Square program stuck in loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintMagic(1);
    }
    public static void PrintMagic(int n)
    {
        int count = 1;
        int[] array = new int[n];
        int magic = 0;
        while(count<=n)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
            {
                magic += i;
                if(Math.sqrt(magic) == ((int)Math.sqrt(magic)))
                {
                 array[i] = magic;
                 count++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
           System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
```

This program is supposed to print the n number of magic squares(a number that has an integer square root, and is a sum of consecutive numbers.)
ex. The square root of 36 is 6 and 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36

I am passing the method the number 3 in the main function, but am getting stuck in a loop(The candy cane looking bar in blueJ)

Is there something Im not seeing?

Comment: No stuck loop in here: https://ideone.com/6Xz7qS Also note that "double == int" is probably a bad idea, you should subtract and compare to some epsilon

Comment: What you want is not clear. For example, for input 3, what the output will be?

Comment: You must be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Problem is your `array` index depend on `i` which is depend on `count` but your array can have diferent size `n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void PrintMagic(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    int[] array = new int[n];
    int magic = 0;
    for(int i = 0; count < n; i++)
    {
        magic += i;
        if(Math.sqrt(magic) == ((int)Math.sqrt(magic)))
        {
            array[count] = magic;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement is to test whether every consecutive sum is a perfect square or not(1+2+..+n is a perfect square). So what you basically want is:`if(Math.sqrt(n*(n+1)/2) == ((int)Math.sqrt(n*(n+1)/2)))`. [You can refer to the answer by a.yekimov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39374577/5720388). He corrected your code, you can note that magic is nothing but the sum of n consecutive whole numbers.

In your code:
    
    `public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintMagic(1);
    }
    public static void PrintMagic(int n){

        int count = 1;// array index start from 0 in java
        int[] array = new int[n];
        int magic = 0;
        while(count<=n){/*since array index starts from zero, equals is to be

        removed*/

            for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++){/*the loop termination should be at
            count<n not i<=count*/
                magic += i;
                if(Math.sqrt(magic) == ((int)Math.sqrt(magic))){
                array[i] = magic;
                count++;
                }
             }
         }
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
           System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }`

You can also try:
    `public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintMagic(3);
    }
    public static void PrintMagic(int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int[] array = new int[n];
        int magic = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(count<n){
            magic += i;
            if(Math.sqrt(magic) == ((int)Math.sqrt(magic))){
                array[count] = magic;
                count++;
            }
            i++; 
        }
        for(i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }`